# Discord bot not reading message.content

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, chat

My bot is not reading the Discord chat. I want it to read the chat and if it finds certain words it will give a certain response. This is my current message event code. This is my first JavaScript project and I have just started learning it so please rip it apart so I can learn quicker :)

At the moment I can get the bot to load into discord. I can turn it on with .node but I can not get it to read a message using message.content.

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILD_MESSAGES", "DIRECT_MESSAGES"] }); 


var name = "Poker Bot";
var usersHand
let firstCardValue  
let secondCardValue
let firstCardSuit
let secondCardSuit 


//starts the bot and sets activity to a funny quote. it also will give a command prompt notification that the
// bot is online

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Bot is online: ${name} !`);
    client.user.setActivity('Burning The Fucking Casino Down');
});
    //check discord chat to see if a user has posted.
client.on("messageCreate", message => {
   //console.log is there to test user input. If it works the message in the discord channel will appear in console
    console.log(`The user has said: ${message} `);

//look for poker hand ~~~ position ~~~~ event (ex: AA CO PF )     (PF= PreFlop)


if (message.content.toLowerCase == 'AK' || message.content.toLowerCase == 'AA' || message.content.toLowerCase == 'KK'){

    message.reply("RECOMMENDED PLAY SHOVE: ALL IN")
}
```

Comment: To make it case insensitive, as I said in my answer, you need to use `.toLowerCase()`, which is in fact a String method, while you're using it as a property, so `message.content.toLowerCase() == "ak"` is what you need to have, then the same for the other options

Answer (score 5):

`.content` is not a method, it's a property, you must now also enable the `Message Content` intent on your bot page as well as in your code.

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILD_MESSAGES", "DIRECT_MESSAGES"] }); 

client.on("messageCreate", message => {
    // || "String" like you did before would return "true" in every single instance, 
    // this is case sensitive, if you wanna make it case insensitive 
    // use `message.content.toLowerCase() == "lowercasestring"`
    if (message.content == "AK" || message.content = "AA" || message.content == "KK") {     
        message.channel.send("Recommend Play is to shove all in" + message.author);
    }
})

client.login(token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your information, you dont just want to send a response if the message contains **only** those strings, but may just contain then.
To check for that, I would suggest to use [regex#test](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Still as [@iiRealistic_Dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16274464/iirealistic-dev) rightfully mentioned: `message.content` is not a function, so removing the brackets is the way to go.

```js
client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {

  if (/AK|AA|KK/.test(message.content)) {
    message.channel.send("Recommend Play is to shove all in" + message.author);
    console.log('it got to here');
  }
});
```

Comment: While this is valid, I think it's best they are shown a proper way to use the logical or operator instead of throwing them straight into using Regexp. It's clear they're beginners