# how to save a discord chat message to a variable using message.content

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I am building a discord bot where I will need to save a users message in a variable but I currently can not get message.content to come up in console.log as well as I can not get my bot to respond to if it reads a certain string in the discord channel.

```
var name = "Poker Bot";
var allIn = "PUSH ALL IN";
var fold = "FOLD";
var tripleBBRaise = "3 BB RERAISE"

let usersHand;


//starts the bot and sets activity to a funny quote. it also will give a command prompt notification that the bot is online
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log(`Bot is online: ${name} !`);
    client.user.setActivity('Burning The Darn Casino Down');
});

    //check discord chat to see if a user has posted.
client.on("messageCreate", message => {

    /*test to see if the chat input works.if working the users message will be saved as a string and then written in the console*/
    console.log(`The user has said: ${message} `);

//Users input will be a poker hand. If it is one of the 3 below then tell the user the given string 
if (message.content.toLowerCase == '/AK' || message.content.toLowerCase == '/AA' || message.content.toLowerCase == '/KK'){
    message.channel.send(`RECOMMENDED PLAY: ${allIn}`) + message.author
}
   
});
```

Comment: Is your messageCreate event emitting at all?

Comment: no and I tried copying directly from multiple tutorials and modifying the parts I need but I can not get anything to work at all.

Comment: What version of discord.js are you using?

Comment: @MrMythical I just installed it yesterday so I assume V13

Comment: What are your client's intents?

Comment: @MrMythical const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: ["GUILD_MESSAGES", "DIRECT_MESSAGES"] });

Comment: Add `"GUILDS"` to the intents

Comment: Not to mention a few more things: `toLowerCase` is a method, not property, it will never == "/AK" either if you're comparing the lowercase version of a string to an uppercase string (it should be `message.content.toLowerCase() == "/ak"`
and
`message.channel.send()` has the `message.author` bit conceanted outside and won't be included

Answer (score 0):

I answered majority of this on your [original post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69893120/discord-bot-not-reading-message-content/69893828#69893828) in a comment since I saw your edit.

If not yet done, you must enable the `Message Content` intent on your bot on [Discord Developer Portal - Applications](https://discord.com/developers/applications) (then select your Application, click the "Bot" button, scroll down to [Priveleged Gateway Intents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHXv7.png) then turn on "Message Content", and, probably, depending on your plan, "Server Members")

If your bot ever reaches 100 servers, assuming it's public, you'll need to verify your bot to continue using intents.